# Ads showing in other devices but not in my device for my apps

Tags: android, firebase, admob, ads, kotlin-android-extensions

After I published my app. I wanted to make some little changes I kept using the real ad unit ids and after sometime I started getting this error, with same ids, test ids, ads were working fine, I changed no layouts or code, interstitial not working too:

```
Failed to load ad: 0
```

Now ads are working on other physical device but not mine. Test ad unit ids are also not working. I can't see ads in my all applications on play store or local.

I am here to ask that is this some sort of block by Google for this device specific to my own apps?
I can see ads in other apps on my phone.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR ... Something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.. check your ad fill rate also check if there are any payment issues listed on admob console?

Comment: I checked email and admob but no notification. This is happening now for 3 days.  Ads are working fine in the world except my device for my apps.